# Is there a way to list the available variables in an Ruby ERB template?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

Suppose I have a Ruby ERB template named **my_template.html.erb**, and it contains the following:

```
<div><%= @div_1 %></div>
<div><%= @div_2 %></div>
<div><%= @div_3 %></div>
```

Is there a way I can programatically list out all the available variables in the template?

For example, the following method:

```
def list_out_variables
  template = File.open("path_to/my_template.html.erb", "rb").read
  erb = ERB.new( template )
  erb.this_method_would_list_out_variables  
end
```

would return something like:

```
['div1','div2','div3']
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: Don't know if it's actually possible, but it seems like a bad idea to me. Normally, view depends on controller, not other way around.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**To get a list of variables available to your .erb file (from the controller):**

Add a breakpoint in the erb:

```
<% debugger %>
```

Then type [instance_variables](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#inspecting-variables) in the debugger to see all of the available instance variables.

Added: Note that [instance_variables](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M000366) is a method available from the Ruby class Object and all of its subclasses. (As noted by @mikezter.) So you could call the method programmatically from within your sw rather than using the debugger if you really wanted to.

You'll get back a list of instance variables for the current object.

**Added: To get a list of the variables used by an .erb file:**

```
# <template> is loaded with the entire contents of the .erb file as
# one long string
var_array = template.scan(/(\@[a-z]+[0-9a-z]*)/i).uniq
```

Comment: @mikezter: -1? Seems a bit harsh. The debugger docs (see link in answer) aren't so clear. I would have upvoted your comment if you'd simply pointed out that typing instance_variables in the debugger is really sending that method name to the current object.

Comment: Thanks for the help! For anyone else: the capture group within the regex (the parenthesis) is unnecessary, and causes a nested array instead of just an array of the variable names.

Comment: I just add <%= instance_variables %> to the .erb file to check them.