# List all available variables in a view for rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm working with a fairly complex app someone else wrote and its not always entirely clear what variables have/have not been created and made available to the view.

Is there a way to dump all the available view variables to the screen from within the .erb?

Comment: You might want to check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800515/is-there-a-way-to-list-the-available-variables-in-an-ruby-erb-template)...

Comment: @summea I have and it wasn't much help. The `template` method lists the variables you're already using and the `<%debugger%>` line doesn't seem to do anything, or else the answer in incomplete.

Answer (score 5):

It seems like this:

```
<%= instance_variable_names.inspect %>
```

Will list all the variables available to the view from within the ERB. 40 minutes of googling and reading paid off.

Answer (score 2):

Building off of Will's answer: you can also do

`<% pp instance_variable_names %>`

where `pp` pretty prints the array. If you do it this way, you'll just have to look in the server logs.